# Javascript needed to fill remaining height space between content and footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, height

How can I set a "spacer" div to fill remaining height space between CONTENT and FOOTER, so footer will be always at the bottom of the page (not window as originally asked)? 
Here is a example where footer is not at the window's bottom: http://template1.staceyapp.com/ (I'm using this template, so structure is the same).
I've tried many things like creating a div and setting it to be min-height, height 100% etc. 
Probably Javascript is needed for that. 
Are you able to help me setting jQuery to calculate it's height to fill the remaining space?
Is there a better solution?

Many thanks in advance,
Graxa

Comment: I'm so confused by your request. You don't want it at the bottom of the window, you just want it to show up after the end of the content? That's what block level elements do by default. Just add your footer after your container div and it'll work how you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to position the footer at the bottom of the page.

by using `position: fixed` or if the footer is contained within another div (container)
set the `position` of that to `relative` and the `position` of your footer to `absolute` and then specify `bottom: 0;` for your footer to keep it locked to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I wrote it wrong when I said "bottom of the window". I mean in the bottom of the PAGE. It's because there will be some pages longer (in height) than the window. In this case I just want the footer to be under all content not in window's fixed bottom. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a sticky footer, which sits at the bottom of the browser window or at the bottom of the content, whichever happens to be longer.

If that's true, check out: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: I have tested it before, but setting 'html, body {
height: 100%; }'cracks my css gradient background. The gradient assumes 100% of the body size or the window size (the one which is smaller) and keeps repeating itself till the end of the page. Thank you.

Comment: Here is the real site I'm working on to you understand: http://www.helenrodel.com.br/future/oliver/?/collections/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the footer just to position:fixed on the bottom?

Comment: As stated on Mark Walters answer I want it on the bottom the page not on window's bottom. Thanks for thinking it with me.

Comment: Then you only need to put the footer in an own div that follows directly your content-wrapper-div